# No Data Output To External Display

Tags: display, 22.04, raspberrypi, arm, 22.10

I have been using Ubuntu 22.04 ARM on a Raspberry Pi 400 for a while, and it was working fine; but it started causing some issues. Currently I have no issues, but I am just asking to know why it did this, and so I know a fix if it happens again.
Running Ubuntu 22.04.1 - Perfectly fine; disk and memory half full. Suddenly, after active for about an hour, the monitor turns black. I did everything possible to "wake it up" but nothing worked. Powered down with the power button and rebooted. Same thing again; after active for about an hour, the monitor turns black.
Eventually the time from power on to the screen going irreversibly black started getting shorter, soon only booting to the sign-in page and then failing to start the desktop. On the locked screen, however, it flawlessly could access the terminal.
The system became useless; so after backing up my data with another computer, I installed Ubuntu 22.10, thinking maybe it may fix the issue.
Running Ubuntu 22.10 - Perfectly fine. It ran smooth at first, but then one day it only showed the color test image, then nothing when I booted it. Again backing up my data, I reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04.1.
Running Ubuntu 22.04.1  So far, so good. This is where I am now, and the screen works fine. UPDATE (Dec. 30, 2022): Never installed Flatpak, yet the screen is now causing problems.

**Impossible Causes:**

1. The display - Works with any other device or OS on the Pi. I tried another monitor, but it also went black.
2. The Pi - It can run any other OS just fine.
3. The SD Card - It works on any other device when formatted

**Possible Causes:**

1. The OS - It failed twice and the hardware never failed.
2. A program - I had Flatpak and it's apps on the two failing attempts; I have not put it on the current (working) one, and I've had no issues.
3. Something else.

P.S. No extra drivers are available in the "Additional Drivers" app.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same issues on my Pi 400. I don't have a fix.

22.04 is the best I run on mine, but I have a USB to M.2 SATA adapter on mine since the SD card is WAY to slow for usability.

I have basically turned everything off to prevent the Pi from sleeping or turning off the monitor.

it's not a fix but it helps

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1288773)